# python pexpect - not taking the expect output

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm using pepexpect to login into a router. The way  I do it is by login into a linux server and then to the routers.

```
usr = 'myusername'
pwd='mypwd'
child.sendline('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l '+usr+' '+ip)
index = child.expect(['assword:', pexpect.EOF,pexpect.TIMEOUT])
```

When I login into the router manually, I get the following:

```
WARNING NOTICE: This is a private system. The actual or attempted, unauthorized
access, use or modification of this system is strictly prohibited.
Individuals undertaking such unauthorized access, use or modification are
subject to company disciplinary proceedings and/or criminal and civil penalties
under applicable domestic and foreign laws. The use of this system may be
monitored and recorded for administrative and security reasons in accordance
with local law. If such monitoring and/or recording reveals possible evidence
of criminal activity, the results of such monitoring may be provided to law
enforcement officials. Continued use of this system after receipt of this
notice constitutes consent to such security monitoring and recording.
!
Global Baseline Configuration:  v1.0

Cisco Wide Area Application Engine

username@10.58.218.237's password:
```

Even thought the password is on the output the index result is 2 = pexpect.TIMEOUT
My script work onb other routers, but I don't know why is not working on this one. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you mean `assword`?

Comment: yes, assword will work for Password and password.

Comment: Are you sure the password prompt is coming from the remote server rather than from the software you're using to log in, and that the server sends the prompt even if it thinks it's talking to a script?

Comment: That prompt that I had on the question is from the cisco router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a hard time using pexpect in order to fill prompts but I've managed to write something working:

```
def call_and_type(command, prompt_regex, entry):
    p = pexpect.spawn(command, logfile=sys.stdout, maxread=16384)
    index = p.expect_exact([prompt_regex, pexpect.EOF])
    if index == 0:
        p.setecho(False)
        p.sendline(entry)
        while p.read():
            pass
```

Comment: I added the maxread=16384 and still having issues. Is there a way to see what pexpect are seeing when sending a command?

Comment: I think you should first try my code in a shell, with for example `command = "sudo apt-get update"` and `entry = "wrong password"`.
This code should output everything to stdout.

Comment: My code was not the problem, the problem was my code, but I was able to figure out with the logfile=sys. The problem that I had is that I was running my script on a list of devices. On one of the devices I encounter a new issue for the next site on the list was having issue because I didn't catch the new issue. Thanks